# jQuery to change dynamically the values of progress-bar "aria-valuenow" attribute and CSS "width" property inside bootstrap collapse component

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have this snippet code from my HTML. May I ask how I can change dynamically the width of each progress bar inside each bootstrap collapse component? My expected output is that when I click the collapse component, it will show all the progress bar inside of it, each progressing until it reaches its respective desired value.

```
<p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Link with href
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
        Link with href
      </a>
  </p>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="skill mb-4">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <h6 class="font-weight-bold">CSS</h6>
            <h6 class="font-weight-bold">85%</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-warning progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skill mb-4">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <h6 class="font-weight-bold">HTML</h6>
            <h6 class="font-weight-bold">95%</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse1" id="collapseExample1">
    <div class="skill mb-4">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <h6 class="font-weight-bold">CSS</h6>
            <h6 class="font-weight-bold">85%</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-warning progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skill mb-4">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <h6 class="font-weight-bold">HTML</h6>
            <h6 class="font-weight-bold">95%</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I put on my JavaScript but it didn't work.
I am just a beginner in web development. I hope you understand me asking this one. I have tried digging out from this platform but I haven't found any clues on the dynamic progress bar inside a collapse component. Thanks again for the help.

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    /*==================== COLLAPSE ===========================*/ 
    $('#collapseExample').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        $('.collapse .skill .progress .progress-bar').each(function () {
            $(this).css("width", $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + '%');
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

I put here the code functional for the snippet. Let me know if you can't access it. My expected output is like those 6 progress bars driven by waypoint function in my JavaScript found in script.js. I want the two progress bars from each collapse component to function the same which I tried to implement in progress-bar.js but it can also be integrated to script.js.
[folder containing the snippet of the code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18DR_OgNgT2o8BBsKV8tUzjJDfUgiVeCK?usp=sharing)

Comment: where are your bootsrap include statements? Please post your whole html, javascript and css code

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18DR_OgNgT2o8BBsKV8tUzjJDfUgiVeCK?usp=sharing

Hi. I put it on my drive. Let me know if you can access it. I deleted sections not relevant to my question @woodz. TIA.

BTW. My expected output is similar to the one with the waypoint function but only those inside the collapse component will be dynamic when each button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do here is change your `.css` jQuery function to a `animate`. Though I don't think this completely achieves what you want.

```
    $(this).animate({
        "width": $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + '%', 
    });
```

To improve upon this you could test for the width of the progress-bar and change the width of "aria-valuenow" based on if that value is 0 or not.

```
    if ($(this).width() < 100)
    {
            $(this).animate({
            "width": $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + '%', 
        });
    } else {
            $(this).animate({
            "width": '0%', 
            });
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fatchild/7bhx8msz